# Production certificates not working for APNS but works for APNS_SANDBOX in AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

We have one of our live iOS Application in the App store and we are facing following issue while integrating SNS :

While creating a new Platform Application on SNS console , APNS does not accept the Production certificates but APNS_SANDBOX accepts both production and development certificates .
the error which flashes is :

> Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid
>   (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter;
>   Request ID: 2f24bcbb-1b66-589f-b0f1-f14baa098c46)

Comment: Anything on this? Having somewhat similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826722/aws-sns-weird-error