# AWS SNS Weird Error

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have created my iOS Application's Development certificate and APNS certificate and together with both have created my .p12 through KeyChain which I upload to my Application in the AWS SNS Applications. When Load Credentials is executed in Update Application Credentials this error is experienced. A similar problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728950/production-certificates-not-working-for-apns-but-works-for-apns-sandbox-in-aws-s?lq=1). Any help in this area is greatly appreciated:

> Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: You provided a certificate of
>   type OTHER, which cannot be used to create an application of type iOS
>   Development. Please select an application of type OTHER or provide a
>   certificate of type iOS Development (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code:
>   400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID:
>   c07a741a-73ed-55b4-93da-3bc095609445)

Comment: Can you make sure the cert you used is for IOS development? From the error message it seems not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case, I was generating the wrong type of certificate.

Instead of generating an **Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)** certificate, I was generating an **iOS App Development** certificate.

[image: Apple developer certificate]

After I created the correct one, Amazon SNS accepted it succesfully.